# qsort array of pointers to linked list, by struct member value

Tags: c, linked-list, qsort

I'm trying to sort an array of pointers to linked list by their id, using qsort function. How i can compare array based on id, not by memory addresses?
I can get values from array simply by dereference it, but id doesn't work in compare function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  int id;
  struct node *next;
};

int sort_items(const void *item, const void *item2) {
  struct node *a = (struct node *) item;
  struct node *b = (struct node *) item2;

  return (a->id) - (a->id);
}

void sort_linked_list(struct node *pntr) {
  const int size = 1024;
  int i = 0, j;
  struct node *current_node = pntr;
  struct node **sorted_array = malloc(sizeof(struct node*) * size);

  while(current_node != NULL) {
    sorted_array[i] = current_node;
    current_node = current_node -> next;
    i++;
  }

  qsort(sorted_array, size, sizeof(struct node *), sort_items);

  for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    printf("%d\n", sorted_array[j]); 
  }

}

void print_list(struct node *start) {
  while(start != NULL) {
    printf("Node id in linked list: %d\n", start->id);
    start = start->next;
  }
}

int main (void) {
  struct node *node1, *node2, *node3, *node4, *node5, *node6, *node7;

  node1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node2 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node3 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node4 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node5 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node6 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node7 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  node1->id = 2;
  node1->next = node2;
  node2->id = 1;
  node2->next = node3;
  node3->id = 3;
  node3->next = node4;
  node4->id = 6;
  node4->next = node5;
  node5->id = 5;
  node5->next = node6;
  node6->id = 4;
  node6->next = NULL;

  sort_linked_list(node1);

  print_list(node1);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: `(a->id) - (a->id);` *cough*

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, was trying to implement a lot of   function variations and mistyped return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code (in addition to the typo that Michael commented on). I'll help you with the subtle error that you might not be able to figure out on your own.

`qsort` passes two pointers to the compare function that you provide. Each pointer points to one item in the array of items that is being sorted. If the array is an array-of-pointers (which is what you have), then the arguments to the compare functions are of type `pointer-to-pointer`. Hence, the code needs to dereference the pointer twice to get the `id`.

One possible implementation of the compare function is

```
int compare( const void *item1, const void *item2 )
{
    struct node *a = *(struct node **)item1;   // first dereference gets the pointer to the struct
    struct node *b = *(struct node **)item2;    

    return( a->id - b->id );   // second dereference using -> notation gets the id
}
```

For the sake of completeness, the other problems in the code are

- the second argument passed to `qsort` should be the number of items
  in the array, not the size of the memory allocated for the array
- the code needs to recreate the linked list from the sorted array, or
  the `print_list` function will simply print the unsorted list
- the `sort_linked_list` function should count the number of items in
  the list before allocating memory.  Either that, or it should throw
  an error if there are too many items in the list.

Comment: Thanks, i read about double dereference in other SO questions, tried this implementation, i got Segmentation fault error with current code (with fixed return statement of course)

Comment: @V.K. Yup, the segmentation fault is a separate issue, and is due to the fact that you are passing `1024` as the second argument to `qsort` even though the array only has six items in it.

Comment: Thank you! Changed second argument to actual array size, now gonna try to restore linked list from that array

Comment: @V.K. Glad to help! I've added one more bullet to the list of problems, since buffer overflows are a hot topic these days (for security reasons), so I would be remiss not to mention it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
int sort_items(const void *item, const void *item2) {
  struct node *a = (struct node *) item;
  struct node *b = (struct node *) item2;

  return (a->id) - (a->id);
}
```

this:

```
(a->id) - (a->id)
```

should probably be this:

```
(a->id) - (b->id)
```

because the first will always return 0, and the second will return 0 only if the id of a and b are the same